# Как дублировать данную карту на сайт заказчика?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, map, карты

Обслуживаю сайт клиента, поставщик медицинского оборудования. 
Было дано задание поместить данную специфичную карту https://yandex.ru/maps/covid19 на сайт. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Самый простой способ:
Меню - Поделиться - "Код для вставки на сайт" Через API не понял как использовать готовую карту + нужно изменить цвета меток.
Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы вставлять Яндекс карты на сайт у Яндекс есть API яндекс карт, которое позволяет использовать любые карты Яндекс на Вашем сайте.

Ссылка на API - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps%20/

Если вы вообще далеки от темы API можете прочесть статью на эту тему - https://vps.ua/blog/how-api-works/

API у Яндекс карт бывает бесплатное и платное, у бесплатного есть свои ограничения, какой тип вам подходит больше зависит от количества клиентов и ваших потребностей.

Comment: А как, допустим, с API скопировать данную по ссылке карту?
Где взять необходимые данные?